# how to return/pass value from javascript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

A rather trivial question, how do I return or pass a value outside the function?

Code below:

```
function numberOfDivs(){
 var numberOfElements = $("#div").children().length; //this count how many divs exist
 return numberOfElements;
}

$("#element").click(function(){
  numberOfDivs();   
  console.log(numberOfElements);// here I need to return the number but getting error :(
});
```

many thanks

Comment: This is a callback of an async function. You can't return anything directly.

Comment: @medzi, this is pretty basic stuff, maybe you should pick a tutorial and get more used to the language.

Comment: @Danilo, where do you see an async call here? This is a simple matter of storing the value returned by `numberOfDivs()`.

Comment: `.click` method attaches an event listener to node of id `element`, and therefore is async

Comment: @Danilo, the caller being async is not a problem, as long as the callee (`numberOfDivs()`) is not async itself (which it isn't).

Comment: I know, but what I understand of his comment in the 8th line is that he wants to return this value to the global scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#element").click(function(){
  var numberOfElements= numberOfDivs();   
  console.log(numberOfElements);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
var numberOfElements= numberOfDivs();   
console.log(numberOfElements);
```

As the function is to return a value, while we invoke the function we assigned a variable to capture the result

Answer (score 1):

```
var numberOfElements;    
function numberOfDivs(){
    numberOfElements = $("#div").children().length; //this count how many divs exist
            }

    $("#element").click(function(){
             console.log(numberOfElements);// here I need to return the number but getting error :(
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is : define `numberOfElements` in global scope like this :

```
var numberOfElements;
function numberOfDivs(){
 numberOfElements = $("#div").children().length; //this count how many divs exist
 return numberOfElements;
}

$("#element").click(function(){
  numberOfDivs();   
  console.log(numberOfElements);// here I need to return the number but getting error :(
});
```

Or another way is : assign  the result in one variable and use that

```
$("#element").click(function(){
      var output = numberOfDivs();   
      console.log(output);// here I need to return the number but getting error :(
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using Callback functions, consider a scenario where incase your numberofDivs function takes time to return the value, it will not give the appropriate results as Jquery is an asynchronous. See this demo for the use of callback to return the data [CALLBACK DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QUWLN/)

```
function AppendJson(callback) {
   var numberOfElements = "AppendJson";
   callback(numberOfElements)
}


AppendJson(function (ReturnValue) {
   alert(ReturnValue);
});
```